# QT : Updating an image as a QLabel with QPixmap

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, user-interface

I am using the QT integrated designer in Visual Studio 2010 to design a simple GUI. Here is what I want to do: I want to click a button called **Update** and use that to change an image that is displayed. I've verified that I am able to trigger a signal by pressing an update and used a slot on a text-field to clear. But can't seem to change the image displayed using the Signal/Slot method ....

Here is the relevant code snippet (GUI.cpp):

```
 void GUI::changeImage() 
 {
     ui.Image->updatesEnabled();
     ui.Image->setPixmap(QPixmap("D:\\Documents\ and\ Settings\\Image.jpg"));
     ui.Image->update();
 }

GUI::GUI(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
    : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    connect(ui.updateButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), ui.textField, SLOT (clear()) );
    connect(ui.updateButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), ui.Image, SLOT ( changeImage() ) );
}

GUI::~GUI()
{

}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: The code for gui.h

```
#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_gui.h"

class GUI : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    GUI(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WFlags flags = 0);
    ~GUI();

private:
    Ui::GUIClass ui;
    void changeImage() ;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slot belongs to the `GUI` class instance, not to `ui.Image`, so you should use `this` as the target in the `connect` call.

```
connect(ui.updateButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT ( changeImage() ) );
```

The slots have to be declared under a "slots" section:

```
private slots:
    void changeImage() ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply alex. I've tried that however it doesn't seem to make any difference. I must clarify that Image is basically a QLabel. I've used the designer to initially set it to an image (using PixMap). And I'm now using the code to transition the image. But it doesn't update the image and maintains the initial one I had specified using the QT Designer -> pixmap -> original image field ...

Comment: Putting break points in my code, it seems that the changeImage function is not even invoked when the updateButton has been pressed ... I guess, I'm incorrectly using SLOTS somehow?

Comment: @c0d3rz Did you put the Q_OBJECT macro in the GUI class definition ?

Comment: Hey Alex, yes I did. It was generated by default actually. I've updated my post to reflect the contents of the gui.h file.

Comment: Thank you very much Alex. I've placed the private slots: section in my gui.h file and I see the image now update itself. I was also step through the code ... thanks again!

Comment: Just one last question. Is there a way I can automatically re-size the image if it is larger than the QLabel, so that it fits into it exactly? Also is this the fastest way of updating images? Or would you recommend an alternative method?

Comment: To resize the image, you can set the label's "scaledContents" property to `true` in the designer, set its size policies to "ignored", with non-zero stretching values if you want it to resize when the window is resized but not when the image size changes (or to "fixed" but you'll have to set the minimum and maximum sizes). And you don't need to call `updatesEnabled()` or `update()`.